# How to have customize log format for "set -x" in bash/ shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, logging

I would like to log out all my "set -x" output into my syslog file.
However, the syslog file has my own custom format.

But set -x output does not have formatting.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `print_cmd.c` in the Bash source code, you'll see that the format of `set -x` output is not configurable.

You could trap the `DEBUG` "signal" to implement your own custom logging, e.g.

```
trap 'logger -p user.debug -t SHELLSCRIPT -- "$BASH_COMMAND" || :' DEBUG
```

to send all commands to syslog with facility `user`, level `debug`, and tag `SHELLSCRIPT`.

Comment: I found that $BASH_COMMAND does not do variable substitution. that is it would output the variable name instead of actual variable. How can we tackle that?